# shell script variable not passing

Tags: bash, shell

I have a snippet of a shell script like so -

```
status() {
        if [ -x "$PRGDIR/qtcat_ctl.sh" ]; then
                echo "Status-ing qtcat Server"

                if [ -z "$QTCAT_RUNTIME_USER" ]; then
                        eval $PRGDIR/qtcat_ctl.sh status
                else
                        su - $QTCAT_RUNTIME_USER -c $PRGDIR/qtcat_ctl.sh status
                fi

                RETVAL=$?
        else
                echo "Startup script $PRGDIR/qtcat_ctl.sh doesn't exist or is not executable."
                RETVAL=255
        fi
}
```

If `QTCAT_RUNTIME_USER` is set to "" the script runs fine but if I try to set `QTCAT_RUNTIME_USER` to another account the `status` parameter does not get passed to the `qtcat_ctl.sh` script.

Comment: If the variable does not exists, it is replaced by the empty string, so it does not work when `QTCAT_RUNTIME_USER` is set to the empty string. The variable is simply never set.

Comment: actually the problem was not the variable it was the actual command.  I had to wrap it in quotes like so:  `su - user -c "/opt/QASymphony/qtest/qtest/bin/qtcat_ctl.sh status"`

Comment: Always enclose your variables in double quotes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need to send an argument to your program via su, you have to quote all the command.

Example with the program a.sh :

```
$ cat a.sh
echo a.sh $1

$su - $USERNAME -c $PWD/a.sh test
a.sh
$su - $USERNAME -c "$PWD/a.sh test"
a.sh test
```